# Consequences of projecting data onto lower dimensions

Tags: python, matplotlib

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.mlab as mlab
import math

na = 400

ma = [2, 1]

Sa = [[3, -2], [-2, 3]]

sigma1 = [3, 3]

nb = 400

mb = [8, 6]

Sb = [[3, -2], [-2, 3]]

xa, ya = np.random.multivariate_normal(ma, Sa, na).T

xb, yb = np.random.multivariate_normal(mb, Sb, nb).T

plt.plot(xa, ya, 'x')    
plt.plot(xb, yb, 'x')    
plt.axis('equal')    
plt.show()
```

I have randomly generated data from 2-dimensional Gaussian Distributions and need to project this on `w=[0, 1]` and plot the histogram. I tried using `plt.hist` but it does not allow the multiplication.

Comment: see https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/201921/transforming-data-on-the-principal-components-axis

Comment: Thanks for the link it was very useful. My difficulty is how I am going to be able to break down the 2d array to be able to do the dot product as my data when np= 10 is like this.    [array([ 1.63383494,  4.6541953 ,  2.10788923,  2.46806161,  1.87287563,
        0.76323836,  2.95160091,  1.74592451, -1.27726486,  4.22058637]), array([ 2.48245559,  1.57752103, -1.23525301, -1.76199059, -0.38459408,
        1.78905969, -2.03621301,  1.23246001,  1.89331416, -0.71733151])]. I know that the first projection should come out as [11/5; 5.75/5] when taking w as [2;1]

Comment: you'll need to cast the arrays as `np.array` and for dot product, use `np.dot`.

Comment: Question has nothing to do with `machine-learning` - kindly do not spam the tag (removed).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below links may be useful for learning numpy.

https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.0/user/basics.creation.html
https://jakevdp.github.io/PythonDataScienceHandbook/02.02-the-basics-of-numpy-arrays.html

I think what you are asking is the below:

```
w = np.array([2,1])
a = np.array([xa,ya]).T
b = np.array([xb,yb]).T

aw = np.dot(a,w)
bw = np.dot(b,w)

plt.figure(0)
plt.hist(aw,label='a',histtype='step')
plt.hist(bw,label='b',histtype='step')
plt.title('projected')
plt.legend()
```